# Get prop from object if it exists otherwise return object

Tags: typescript

I'm tying to write a function that will return the `data` prop from an object and if it doesn't have one return the object itself as a fallback. Here's my attempt.

```js
type Maybe<T, P extends string> = T extends { [K in P]?: infer R } ? R | undefined : T

function maybeData<T>(obj: T): Maybe<T, 'data'> {
  return obj && typeof obj === 'object' && 'data' in obj ? obj.data : obj
}
```

This results in `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<T, "data">'.`

Is there away of writing this without resorting to casting the return value?

Comment: Assigning to a conditional type is usually nearly impossible. Are you sure you don't want overloads instead? Checkout https://tsplay.dev/Nd8PdN. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Right now there's nothing better than "casting" the return value (more conventionally called a *type assertion* in TS). TS can't refine the generic type parameter `T` by checking `obj`; the relevant open feature request is at [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Overloads are essentially equivalent to just asserting that the implementation meets all call signatures.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?